# Matrix library vs for loops for element-wise operations in Java

Tags: java, matrix

I'm looking to do some some element-wise operations (addition, multiplication, sqrt, etc.) on floating point arrays that are ~800x300 elements in size.

How much of a speedup (if any) would I get from doing this with matrix libraries (JAMA, EJML, etc.) over just doing the element-wise operations in for loops?

For loops look more appealing because my equations can get kind of complicated, and for loops would mean I could keep all my equations as is -- in plain old infix notation. Since java doesn't support operator overloading, using a matrix library wouldn't be as simple. So, I only want to use a matrix library if it's going to mean a real speedup. (Speed will be important here.)

Comment: What are you going to do? If you just want to "add 3 to each element" (or multiply, or whatever) I doubt you will get any speedup over the "loop everything". Remember to loop in the right order (the more to the right an index is, the more inner its loop must be). This is not directly related to Java but to cache issues.

Comment: There are a number of operations like: Hx[subarray] = DaY*Hx[subarray] + DbY*(Ez[subarray] - Ez[subarray shifted]) where all operations are element-wise and everything in there (Hx, Ez, DbY, DaY) is an array or a large rectangular subsection of an array. Having to frequently select subarrays looks messy with many libraries, but maybe I'm overreacting. I guess that part of my question comes because some libraries can do parallel processing, and I don't know if these arrays would benefit from that (or be slowed down by overhead).

Comment: Your best option is to take some small typical pieces of your matrix operation, and write them as loops and using whichever seems most convenient of the libraries. That way, you can both see how the code looks, and benchmark to resolve the performance issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use some of the matrix libraries for that. In most cases it should run as fast as simple for loops. But it also can run faster. So, what you will get for free: API & the equal or better perfromance. It also saves a bit of your time while writing element-wise operations.

As the author of [la4j](http://la4j.org) library I can say that using third-party library gives you an opportunity to get faster and faster code from new releases. For example. You can choise la4j for you needs. It is currenlty (version 0.4.0-0.4.5) uses simple for loops calculations for element-wise operations. So, it won't be faster then hand-written code. But, I'm now on the middle of developing a new **parallel engine** for la4j, that allows to run a code in parallel mode without any significant changes in API. Like this:

```
Matrix a = new Basic2DMatrix(...); // simple 2D array matrix
Matrix b = new Basic2DMatrix(...); // that is too

Matrix c = a.multiply(b); // a * b in sequental mode

Matrix c = a.par().multiply(b); // a * b in parallel mode
```

So, all you need to do is change a one piece of the code. All these advantages you'll get for free with libraries like la4j. Just let the libraries do their job and spend your solving real problems.